# Selling on Amazon.com or eBay.com on Shabbos or Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, shabbat, internet, transactions

There are some Rabanim that do not allow you to sell via your own website on Shabbos / Yom Tov. If you sell books on Amazon.com or eBay.com where you do not collect the money nor fulfill the order on Shabbos / Yom Tov (as they process the credit card and first give you the money at a later date) would it still be Assur to leave your listings active on Shabbos / Yom Tov?

Comment: [Here is a very Basic answer.](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/718907/Rabbi_Josh_Flug/Melachot_Planned_to_Occur_on_Shabbat_Part_II)

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9304

Comment: This question would be easier to give useful answers to if it identified the rabbis in the premise, since the question only comes up according to those rabbis.

Comment: Never even heard of half.com some googling helped me find that it was the predecessor to ebay. :)

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was answered on [dinonline:](http://dinonline.org/2015/12/05/selling-on-amazon-on-shabbos/)

> **Question:**
>   Hello
>   Please can you tell me if it is ok to sell via Amazon and keep the listings up over Shabbos?
>   I am a private seller and do not use Amazon fulfilment. When and item is sold, any money is held by Amazon for a number of days before being transferred automatically to my account
>
> **Answer:**
>
> Assuming your business is not processing any orders on Shabbos this would be permitted. The fact that others are placing orders on Shabbos and giving their credit card information poses no problem for you.
>
> **Sources:**
>
> See Noda Biyhuda (Tinyana, Orach Chaim 26), who writes that there is certainly no problem for somebody to receive money for a sale that is performed on Shabbos.
>
> When the sale is permitted (see Orach Chaim 323:4 concerning purchases for the purpose of Shabbos, and Orach Chaim 245:5 concerning a non-Jew who sells on behalf of a Jew), there is no prohibition of “making money” on Shabbos. Just as it is permitted, in this instance, to “make money,” it is likewise permitted for the sale to be completed.
>
> A similar idea is found in Shut Beis Shlomo (Orach Chaim 36) and in the Tehilla Le-David (244:11).
>
> Based on this principle, authorities have permitted the placement of vending machines (selling drinks or other commodities), even when they will be used on Shabbos (in areas where the use on Shabbos will be by non-Jews; see Shut Maharshag 2:117; Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa, in the name of Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, Chap. 29, note 71). The same would apply to your sale on Amazon