# Having a twitter bot post on shabbat

Tags: shabbat

I am programming a Twitter post to post once a day pre-written tweets.  I currently don't know how to prevent it from posting on Shabbat.  Is a twitter bot posting on Shabbat permitted?

Comment: Also turn all your clocks of on Shabbos

Comment: Please explain why you think it should be a problem..

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34945/170

Comment: @DannySchoemann perhaps it would matter to some if this was for business to drive sales over shabbos. May need more details about what the purpose of the twitter bot is.  See this post: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67229/19100

Comment: The bot is to post a verse from Pirkei Avot every day.  It is not for any business or donation purposes.

Answer (score 4):

See [this article](https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/05/social-media-for-shabbos/) by R. Gil Student which discusses this and other related issues.

Possible problems involve:

- Using a timer to perform work on *shabbat*
- *Marit ayin* - giving the appearance of doing work on *shabbat*
- Running a business on *shabbat* (where applicable)

However, to quote his tentative conclusion:

> My initial reaction is that scheduling blog posts, Tweets, e-mails, etc. should only be done if it is for personal rather than business use and should include a disclaimer stating that it was scheduled before Shabbos.