# App featuring material written on Shabbos & lashon hora

Tags: halacha, shabbat, business, lashon-hara-slander, social-media

I'm building [an Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andromo.dev233649.app217592) featuring Israeli news. It is largely based on feeds that automatically takes material written by news services and bloggers who are not shomer Shabbos (but no one is writing specifically for the app). The app does make a little money from ads, but I'm not selling anything per-se. The app has actually been live for quite a while - it's tough to tell, but at the moment most users are probably not Jewish.

Is it permissible to include such feeds as some material is inevitably written on Shabbos and inevitably some users will 'download' this material before shabbos ends? Note that the material will only reach the user's phone when the (not-necessarily-Jewish) user decides to load the app.

Additionally, are there any issues in providing such content with regards to any Lashon Hora contained within?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45992/11501 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9304/11501 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2671/11501

Comment: Welcome to MY and thanks for bringing this interesting topic to our attention! That said, we try to avoid asking personal halachic questions around here; this type of issue should best be handled by your local orthodox Rabbi.

Answer (score 3):

**The topic of operating apps/sites on Shabbat is complex**, an entire book ([Commerce and Shabbos](http://www.feldheim.com/commerce-and-shabbos.html)) was written on it by R Yosef Y Kushner.

In general it is permitted to write an app that will maybe be used by Jews on Shabbat (and there are thousands like this of course). R Shlomo Aviner writes that, regarding "Do not place a stumbling block", if one is uncertain that the person will transgress the Halachah, we are "tolim" (literally "hanging" on the assumption) that he will not violate it (Mishnah [Gittin 5:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Gittin.5.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) (see bottom of [here](http://www.ravaviner.com/2017/12/short-sweet-text-message-q-341_19.html)).

We also know that

- some sites operated by religious Jews (e.g., B&H Photo) are operating on Shabbat with the commerce function disabled (i.e., you can browse but not buy)
- some sites operated by religious Jews (e.g., artscroll) shut down entirely

R Kushner explicitly addresses a number of relevant topics for your app

- **Operating an e-commerce website on Shabbat** (p. 183): he writes that according to the overwhelming majority of *poskim*, a Jewish-owned website may remain open on Shabbat, for reasons similar to those explained [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67229/11501) (which would explain B&H)
- **Profiting from online advertising on Shabbat** (p. 200): permitted if the earnings generated from ads run on Shabbat are received by the Jewish owner together with the money earned from advertising during the weeks
- **Operating a website used by a majority of Jews** (p. 190): he writes  that it would be better to avoid leaving the website open on Shabbat (which would explain artscroll) - I understand this is not your case but wanted to be complete

So there are likely to be *poskim* who will permit or prohibit based on the specifics of the case. But you really need to speak to a competent rav to review the specifics and get a personal ruling. The above might serve as a helpful review of some of the sources.

---

**Regarding *lashon hara* on the Internet**, there is [a book](http://a.co/bo5ADXC) for this as well :-> (but I don't have it), this [review](http://blogs.timesofisrael.com/book-review-false-facts-and-true-rumors-lashon-hara-in-contemporary-culture/) (bottom) mentions it explicitly addresses issues relevant to your question.

Since newspapers are definitely constrained by the laws of *lashon hara* (see e.g., bottom of [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/oppenheimer-1.htm)), it stands to reason you will need rabbinic guidance on your app as well.

R Dovid Genish  [writes](https://www.hidabroot.com/article/135129/Media-Gossip)

> Newspapers certainly contain much lashon hara, and as the Chofetz
>   Chaim makes clear, the prohibition includes not writing negatively
>   about other individuals, groups or communities. Az Nidberu (14:64)
>   discusses the issue of liability – is it the journalist who has
>   transgressed lashon hara or the publisher/vendor?
>
> His conclusion is that the writer is certainly guilty, for even though
>   at the time of writing he did not tell anyone his lashon hara, once
>   his words are published he has transgressed retroactively. **On the
>   other hand, the publisher or vendor is by and large not liable since
>   he has no intention to spread lashon hara – he merely earns his
>   livelihood by selling newspapers, but does not specifically intend to
>   damage others. Nevertheless, he recommends that one should stay as far away from such newspapers as possible.**

Last, halachayomit [writes](http://www.halachayomit.com/lashon.html) in a way that would make it challenging to automatically republish articles from "non-kosher sources"

> I also contacted Arutz-7, a radio station here in Israel. One of the
>   founders of this station is a Rosh Yeshiva (dean of a Yeshiva), and I
>   believe that they sincerely try to avoid lashon hara. The following is
>   the reply that I received from [them]
>
> Rabbi Zalman Melamed - the Rosh Yeshiva of Yeshivat Beit El, Rabbi of
>   Beit El, and one of the founders of Arutz-7 - is the rabbinic
>   authority of Arutz-7. **His guiding principle is, first of all, that
>   something that is already known (public knowledge) can not always be
>   publicized - as publicizing it further is at least avak lashon hara (a
>   statement which is not lashon hara itself, but will cause lashon hara
>   to be spoken).**
>
> [...]
>
> Equally obviously, the above rules out all sorts of gossip columns,
>   which have absolutely no place in a Torah publication. Similarly,
>   crime stories usually should not have any names mentioned. Even
>   political figures, who are often justifiably criticized based on the
>   above principle of "benefit to the public," should not be mentioned by
>   name in cases that can bring no such benefit - such as how many times
>   he was divorced, or the like. There have been several cases when we
>   have specifically left out names, even though in a "normal" newspaper
>   they would have been mentioned totally matter-of factly".