# Monetizing ads on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, money

Is there any issue with me running adverts on my app since I receive money when people click on the ads on Shabbos?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9304/can-an-ecommerce-website-remain-open-on-shabbat

Comment: Also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4169 (msh210 comment on Danno's linked question)

Comment: Related (about advertising in a third-party app, where this one is about running the third-party ads in your app): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29131